# How to get selected value of dropdown in angular 6 on load(not onchange)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a select dropdown ,I am getting option's data and value from an array through loop. Here I need to get the value of selected drop down when page loads without onchange(in this case Recent). Here is code below.

### app.component.html

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let v of values" [value]="v.id">  
    {{v.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'projectchart';
 public values = [
  { id: 3432, name: "Recent" },
  { id: 3442, name: "Most Popular" },
  { id: 3352, name: "Rating" }
];
  ngOnInit(){
  alert('The default selected value is');
  }


}
```

Comment: Can you use the `FormsModule`?

Answer (score 0):

you could make use of reactive forms

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

// create a form group using the form builder service
formName = this.fb.group({
    name: ['']
})
```

in the template

```
<form [formGroup]="formName">
 <select formControlName="name">
  <option *ngFor="let v of values" [value]="v.id">  
    {{v.name}}
  </option>
 </select>
</>
```

and then get the value in the ts:

```
this.formName.controls['name'].value
```

Comment: Is there any simple method without using formbuilder

Comment: `name: ['']`  added an empty option in select box for me and `this.formName.controls['name'].value` returns NULL always. Is there any modification for this to get the value of select box without prepending the NULL option to the select box.